# How to find document by _id in couchdb?

Tags: java, json, gwt, couchdb

I m trying to fetch document form couchdb by its _id

If the document is present in the database then it returns the document JSON,

Else if document is not present in the database it returns me an exception.

I m trying this in my code :.

```
String dbname="abc";

String Email_Id="uvw@xyz.com";

Session session = new Session("localhost", 5984);

Database database = session.getDatabase(dbname);

Document doc = database.getDocument(Email_id);
```

*(here **dbname** is name of the database and **Email_id** is ._id of the document)*

i have to check whether the document with this email_id is present or not.
Using `getDocument("")` function, for the document which is not present in the database, throw an Exception

**Exception:.** `net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["error"] is not a JSONObject.`

I have to create the document if it is not present in my database.

Comment: can you post the query of your code?

Comment: String dbname="abc";

String Email_Id="uvw@xyz.com";

Session session = new Session("192.168.1.43", 5984);

Database database = session.getDatabase(dbname);

Document doc = database.getDocument(Email_id);
*(here dbname is name of the database and Email_id is ._id of the document)*
i have to check whether the document with this email_id is present or not.
using getDocument function for the document which is not present in the database throw an Execption discussed above.

Comment: Please post this code in the query, you can edit it and add the code formatted so it is more  readable. Also include your imports so as we know which library you are using 'ektorp' ?

Comment: Question updated plz check
and my imports are

`import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database;`

`import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Document;`

`import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session;`

Answer (score 0):

Normally the way to check the existence of a document in couchdb is sending a HTTP [head request](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/03/01/use-your-head-checking-couchdb-document-existence/). Taking a look to the [Database](https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j/blob/master/src/java/com/fourspaces/couchdb/Database.java) class in [couchdb4j](https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j) which is the library you are using in your project, they seem not have a method for doing it. In [ektorp](http://ektorp.org/), another couchdb java library, they have the method [contains](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp/blob/master/org.ektorp/src/main/java/org/ektorp/impl/StdCouchDbConnector.java#L134) which does it.

Thus, you have these options:

1.- Use ektorp instead of couchdb4j in your project.

2.- Implement your own method for doing a [head](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/head.html) request.

3.- Wrap your call in a try catch block.

4.- Open a request to couchdb4j for having a `contain` method using head.

Answer (score 0):

Imports are ( jar file to be used is CouchDb4j.0.1.2.jar)

```
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Document;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.ViewResults;
```

Create below method to check whether email exists or not

```
  boolean emailexists= checkIfExists(couchdbServer, couchdbserverPort, couchDbName, emailid)

    {
    if (emailexists)

    {
    log.debug("email already exists in the database");
    }
    else
    {
    CouchDBHandler cdb = new CouchDBHandler(couchDbName,couchdbServer,couchdbserverPort);

    String addedid = cdb.addEmail(email);

    }
    }


public static boolean checkIfExists(String couchdbServer,String couchdbserverPort,String couchDbName,String idtoCheck) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {


 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 StringBuffer sbserverURL = new StringBuffer();       sbserverURL.append("http://").append(couchdbServer).append(":").append(couchdbserverPort).append("/").append(couchDbName).append("/").append(idtoCheck);

                log.debug("Server URL is:"+sbserverURL.toString());
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(sbserverURL.toString());


                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(instream));
                String strdata = null;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                while( (strdata =reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                       sb.append(strdata);
                }

                if (sb.toString().indexOf("not_found") > -1) {

                    return false;
                }
                else 
                    return true;

            }




    public String addEmail(email)
    {
    Document doc = new Document();//CouchDb4j jar file has this function
    doc.setId(email);
    db.saveDocument(doc); //private Database db; //CouchDb4j jar file has this function
    }
```